# Поиск точного совпадения в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Уперся в задачу которою не могу решить уже очень много времени.
Скрипт делает проверку IP адресса на наличие его в базе, но не получаеться найти точное совпадение, при отправки IP(192.168.1.163) в поиск, получаю
192.168.1.1 ,
192.168.1.16,
192.168.1.163,
Нужно сделать, что бы было 192.168.1.163 == 192.168.1.163 и все без другоих совпадений. Помогите, пожалуйста и прошу строго не судить я новичок. Пример кода.

```
filename = 'ip.txt'
def check(ip):

    base_path = "z-i/dump.csv"
    with open(base_path) as f:
        datafile = f.readlines()
         found = False  # This isn't really necessary
         for line in datafile:
             if  ip in line:
        return True
return False  # Because you finished the search without finding
def get_from_file(filename): # Open the file with IP and in turn send each address for review  
    fd = open(filename, 'r')
    list_ip= []
    for line in fd:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        if check(line):
            print(line + ' => ' + 'In base RKN')    
    fd.close()
    return list_ip
get_from_file(filename)
```

Comment: `if  ip == line:` ?

Comment: Уже так делал, поиск не работает. Думаю через регулярку сделать, но я еще толком с ней не работал и не знаю как сделать корректный шаблон

Comment: Если не работает ``if ip == line``, значит что-то делаете неправильно. Тут не нужно придумывать никаких странных способов в виде регулярных выражений, когда есть примитивный ``==``. Как выглядят данные в файле и как выглядит ip, который сравниваете?

Comment: В дампе поный мусор. Пример сроки. IP обычный адрес.
149.202.99.108;iserver4.tv;newcamd525://iserver4.tv:4001 | newcamd525://iserver4.tv:4002 | newcamd525://iserver4.tv:5000;���������;����������� � ��������������� ����������� �� ��������� � 2�-0384/2015;2015-10-1

Comment: `if ip = line.split(";",1)[0] :`

Comment: C точкой и запятой работает, но в дамп разный не всегда возле IP есть точка, как можна сделать, что бы искать примерно так ,
if ip = line.split(";",1)[0] or if ip = line.split(" ",1)[0] ищем все сначала с точками, если точек уже  нет ищем  все с пробелами?

Comment: а он всегда в самом начале строки?

Comment: Вот еще пример строки дампа
 | 54.89.225.216 | 54.89.234.170 | 54.89.235.233 | 54.89.43.131 | 54.89.51.135 | 54.89.83.105 | 54.89.86.3 |

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/IRTCdZ/1

Comment: когда проверите много образцов строк и поймете, что что-то вышло, можете нажать code generator и увидите, что со всем этим делать

Comment: Так то понятно, но как мне подставить вместо шаблона мою переменую в котрой IP адреса.

Comment: Если я делаю подставлю данный шаблон в поис то я получю на выходе абсолютно все адреса, что есть в дампе

Comment: А что не так? получили все адреса из строки, проверили, что ваш ip там присутствует или нет. Сделали нужные действия

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сначала делаешь импорт либы для регулярных выражений

```
import re
```

А потом регуляркой ищешь все IP в строке дампа. Функция findall возвращает список найденных IP. После этого проверяешь наличие ip в этом списке

```
dump_IPs = re.findall(r"(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9])(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{2}|[0-9]{2}|[0-9])){3}",line)
if ip in dump_IPs:
.....
```

Comment: спасибоооооооо)) то, что нужно скрипт работает но очень медленно))) буду думать как оптимизировать))))